# Starting a powershell command via a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

currently working with a batch file. When the .bat runs it 1. opens a specific website page and 2. runs powershell within a directory.

Is there any way to have a command automatically inputted in powershell when I start the .bat?

This is what I am currently working with, and I'd like to input the commmand "node ."

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
START "C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe" https://stackoverflow.com
START powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd 'C:\Users\[User]\Desktop\File Directory\File in File\File in File in File'"
```

Comment: Multiple PowerShell commands can be strung together on one line by separating them with `;` semicolons.

Comment: The correct syntax is `Start "This is the title" "Quoted Command"`. Even if you don't want or need a title, you need to supply one, if you have a quoted command. Your first `start` line should therefore be `Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe" "https://stackoverflow.com"`. Your second `start` line would also be better defining the working directory as part of the `start` command itself, e.g. `Start "" /D "C:\Users\[User]\Desktop\File Directory\File in File\File in File in File" "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "node ."`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out. A semicolon allows you to chain commands.

```
@ECHO OFF
START "C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"     https://stackoverflow.com
START powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd 'C:\Users\[User]\Desktop\File Directory\File in File\File in File in File'"; "node ."
```

Comment: Please read my comment under your question proper, and please also open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. Both of the lines I've provided in my comment would be better a methodology and syntax for your two submitted commands.

Comment: the brave command won't actually open brave. It opens the URL with the default browser instead: [Weird behavior when launching app from CMD with/without start](https://superuser.com/q/758870/241386), [How do I actually open a program from a batch file? All it does is open a command prompt with that file name](https://superuser.com/q/587131/241386), [Can I use the “start” command with spaces in the path?](https://superuser.com/q/239565/241386)